# comparision operation Sql query with php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
$num=$_POST['data'];
$no = (int) $num;
$sql = "select * from uploads where id > '$no'"
```

The above query not working properly.It is displaying the values below the no.I think the problem with conversion.somebody please help to solve this problem

Comment: Unless you've copied it, I'm not sure `$_post` will work; it should be `$_POST`.

Comment: @user2067403 2nd line of your code, it should be `$no` not `Sno`

Comment: Have you checked whether your `id` column in the table is of integer type?

Comment: You also don't need two variables, e.g., `$no = (int) $_POST['data'];`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `Sno = ...`, it should be `$no = ...`. It's a typo.

Then, numbers in query doesn't require apostrophes, so don't use them in this context.

You also had `$_post` instead of `$_POST` - it's another issue, [variables in PHP are case-sensitive](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php).

Answer (score 1):

You have apostrophes around the value, so the values will be compared as strings, not numbers. The string value `10` for example is smaller than the string value `2`.

Remove the apostrophes:

```
$sql = "select * from uploads where id > $no";
```

Comment: @user2067403: delete the apostrophes from the string. Just as I showed.

Comment: @user2067403 - He is did; the `'` were the problem. Also note that `$no = (int) '';` (as, `$_POST['data']` is empty) will give you `0` in your query. FYI.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code instead:

```
if ( empty( $_POST['data'] ) ){
    // show error message
    echo "No data received";
    // use a default values
    $num = 0;
}
else 
    $num=$_POST['data'];

$no = intval($num);
$sql = "select * from uploads where id > $no";
```

Try to use [intval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) instead of casting to int

Comment: You've got a typo in the `else`.

Comment: Keep in mind the short form without braces can be confusing to non-programmers and beginners. `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
$sql = "select * from uploads where id > ".$no;
```

and also put $_POST instead of $_post

Answer (score -1):

```
$no = (int) $_POST['data']; //wrong variable declaration ?
$sql = "select * from uploads where id > $no";
```

Try this.

`$_post` replaced by `$_POST`

one variable instead of two

Comment: Try explaining where he went wrong and what areas he needs to research to full understand the problem space.